# SE Data Explorer table for link visits

Tags: stackexchange-api, dataexplorer

I would like to use the API or SEDE to discover which of my shared links (created by the "share" button as appears below each question/answer) have been visited by the most unique IP addresses.

Which table is this information stored in? I tried searching [data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) for visits, hyperlink, link, etc. and it looks like no one has created this query yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. Reference [this, barely upvoted, feature request from six years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94525/can-i-see-how-many-unique-ip-addresses-visited-from-one-of-my-links).

That information is not available in the API, SEDE or the Data Dump.

You can see this by reviewing:

1. [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)
2. Particularly [the `user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user), which is a likely place for a pointer to such information
3. The [SEDE and Data Dump, database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)
4. The [SEDE query builder](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Comment: I upvoted the [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94212/364344) that one is a duplicate of, thanks!